# how to install kdm on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, kde, kdm

I installed CentOS 7, first I installed group "KDE Plasma Workspace", then I installed "GNOME Desktop", after that, I found only `gdm` existed. and `which kdm` returns nothing, `yum provides kdm` only returns `kgreeter-xxx` but it has been installed.

My question is whether the kdm removed from CentOS 7. how can install kdm on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 3):

When you install a new system next time do a minimal desktop install with kde. Or you can try this

```sh
yum -y groupinstall "KDE desktop" "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

or you can try add & remove software there you can find it easily.

Comment: Thank you. i tried as you mentioned, install a new system and do a minimal desktop install, then i group install "KDE Plasma Workspaces", there's no 'kdm' but 'gdm' installed. "KDE Desktop"\"X Windows System" doesn't exist in the groups list returned by 'yum groups list'. i think kdm is not included into the centos repo.

Comment: Centos decided that the gdm login was "good enough" and didn't include the kde login - even when using KDE desktop, so we have gnome junk we don't need, plus conflicts where gnome bits were broken, so login was broken - when all we needed was a pure kde login/desktop to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`kdm` is part of package `kde-workspace`, you can try to reinstall it. Also you can enable kdm in `/etc/rc.conf` by adding `kdm4_enable="YES"` line and check if it's really missing.

**update**

KDM has been removed from CentOS 7.

Comment: I have tried reinstall kde-workspace, maybe kdm is removed from package 'kde-workspace'.

Comment: Have you tried adding to rc.conf and reboot?

Comment: i found a post here, http://jbmoore61.blogspot.com/2014/07/no-kde-display-manager-kdm-on-rhel7-and.html. it is likely redhat removes the kdm.

Comment: Yes, you're right. KDM has been removed from RHEL7 and Centos correspondingly. And kde-workspace doesn't have it anymore. [link](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/27434110/dir/centos_7/com/kde-workspace-libs-4.10.5-21.el7.i686.rpm.html) Can't you login to KDE using GDM?

Comment: Yes, I can. I have been used to kdm. Thanks. Should we close this question now ?

Comment: I think yes, since it can't be helped.

Comment: `/etc/rc.conf` does not exist in Centos7.

Comment: Ok, if that has been removed, and since "KDE desktop" does not exist (tried the above answer), then I need to type precisely what at the bash-prompt to install KDE?  I'll start: yum -y groupinstall "????"

Comment: @JosephK have you tried to run `yum|dnf install @kde-desktop`?

Comment: I do not recall for sure what worked, but in my bash-history I found " yum reinstall 'kde*' " - just using the wildcard to do it.  I was unaware of 'dnf' - will look into that when the next centos-gui-desktop-breakage occurs, (probably in a month or so, based on current experience with 7.x).

Answer (score 0):

CentOS-7 "Minimal Install" (no Desktop System)

```
sudo yum groupinstall "X Window System" "Fonts"
sudo yum install lightdm-kde kde-workspace
sudo systemctl --force enable lightdm.service
startx
```

That Desktop setup adds about 500MB to a minimal install.

So less than 2.5GB in virtual box as an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Set default systemd target to graphical.target:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Reboot, or activate immediately:

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

Source: https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-install-kde-plasma-gui-in-centos-7-linux/

Answer (score -1):

Install KDE Desktop Environment on here.

```
yum -y groups install "KDE Plasma Workspaces"
echo "exec startkde" >> ~/.xinitrc
startx
```